# How to get entries with or

Tags: entry, entrymodel, query, elementquery

it is possible to do like this:

```
$users = Entry::find()
  ->userLevel('>3')
  ->or group('admin')
```

So in database level,the sql will go like this:

```
select * from users
  where users.userLevel > 3 or users.group='admin'
```

Many many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes but not like you tried it. You have to work on Yii2 level and not with Crafts Query

```
// prefix for content column tables
// if you want to select fields in the field layout do
// $prefix . 'fieldHandle'
$prefix = Craft::$app->getContent()->contentTable . '.' . Craft::$app->getFields()->oldFieldColumnPrefix; 

$user = User::find()
    ->andWhere(
        new OrCondition(
            ['>','users.userLevel', 3],
            ['=', 'users.group', 'admin'] 
        )
    )
    ->all();
```

However: keep in mind this SQL will likely produce errors because there is neither a `users.group` column nor a `users.userLevel` column in the database

Just as an example for more complex search:

```
$prefix = Craft::$app->getContent()->contentTable . '.' . Craft::$app->getFields()->oldFieldColumnPrefix;
$criteria = [
    'where'     => new OrCondition(
        [
            [
                'between',
                $prefix . 'startDate',
                Db::prepareDateForDb($startDateDb),
                Db::prepareDateForDb($endDate)
            ],
            new AndCondition(
                [

                    ['=', $prefix . 'recurring', 1],
                    ['<=', $prefix . 'startDate', $startDateDb->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')]
                ]
            )
        ]
    ),
    'orderBy'   => ['startDate' => SORT_ASC],
    'sectionId' => 10,
];

$query = Entry::find();
\Craft::configure($query, $criteria);
```

Comment: Thank you. But I know nothing about Yii, so in this way, how can I use relatedTo function?

Comment: You have to join the `relation` table and check if a value exists with your criteria. You can perform a simple query to see what Craft does. `Entry::find()->relatedTo(1)->getRawSql()`